# Securing /admin/ in Struts 1

Tags: struts, spring-security

I have a Struts 1.1 web application and now it needs an admin tool.  I need /admin/* secured so that only registered users can login and view its content.  The data store is MongoDB.

Is Spring Security my best option for securing my site?  Why?

And does anyone know from experience whether Spring Security 3 and Struts 1 works fine together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using Spring Security 3 without any problems.